# Converting two python lines code to PHP

Tags: php, python

I have those two lines of code written in python i want to convert them to php, please help i don't know how to do this in php.

```
#code in python:
vowels= re.compile(ur'[\u064B-\u0652]')
newstr = vowels.sub('', str)
```

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is equivalent:

```
<?php
    $vowels ='/[\x{064B}-\x{0652}]/u'; 
    $newstr = preg_replace($vowels,"",$str);
```

The string should be UTF-8 encoded.

Comment: it works thank you very much, i've made it using another way but your way is the best,

Answer (score 2):

I believe what you want is PHP's [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). I have no idea how PHP handles Unicode so I'm unsure if you can just take the Python pattern as-is and use it with PHP, but the syntax for using `preg_replace()` would be something like this:

```
<?php
$mystring = "jask;lfjalksdf"
$pattern = "/\u064B-\u0652/";
$replacement = "";

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $mystring);
?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i still have that problem with Unicode, the regex expresion is not correct.
I get this error: 
Warning: preg_replace() [function.preg-replace]: Compilation failed: PCRE does not support \L, \l, \N{name}, \U, or \u at offset 1

Answer (score 1):

re.compile() means its compiling a regular expression. Look at [this](http://weblogtoolscollection.com/regex/regex.php) for some help.

The sub function is essentially adding str to the beginning of the regular expression.

More info on python regular expressions can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Comment: Thank you for the links, but my real problem is with the unicode in php i don't knwo how to do the same thinkg in php.